# Don't know what > div does

Tags: html, css

Don't understand the: > div

```
.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;  
}
```

found it here https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flex-wrap_nowrap8

Answer (score 1):

Your code will target all direct children elements of `flex-container` that are div elements.

This is how the `>` selector works in CSS.